# How to preview a html file without saving it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, browser

Hy,

In my application I store a string as content of a html file.

How can I preview this content (assuming that it's modified from original content) in browser but not having to save it local.

**Update**

And the preview to be in another tab or window.

Comment: Do you mean "not have it on disk at all", or "not generate a file that will be persisted"? If it's the later, you can generate a temporary file which would work fine. If you want to do this, you can go with System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() + ".html";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a preview page that just writes the html string to the response like so:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string htmlString = //initialise the string here
        Response.Write(htmlString);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: you have any idea how can I open it in another tab or window? because 'Response.Write()' opens is in the same window...

Answer (score 2):

Using the Control `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`, you can preview your HTML with `DocumentText`

Example:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<HTML><BODY style=\" background-color:black\"></BODY></HTML>";
```

Comment: The question is for asp.Net, otherwise that'd be a good suggestion.